# F# recursive function that takes single point and index

Tags: recursion, syntax, f#, lexical

How do you write a F# recursive function 'something' that takes a single point `(x, y)` and index i as
an arguments and returns an ℎ element of the infinite list corresponding to `S(x, y)`.

ex: let something (x,y) i =

F# function `F(,)` should be defined as:

```
F(x,y)(u, v) = (u2 − v2 + x, 2uv + y)
```

F# function 'something' `(x, y)` of a point `(x, y)` should be an infinite list of items:

```
S(x, y) = {(0, 0), F(x,y)(0, 0), F(,y)(F(x,y)(0, 0)), F(x,y)(F(x,y)(F(x,y)(0, 0))), …}
```

Comment: Well this sounds like an obvious assignment question. Have you tried anything yourself? What specific problem do you have implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an assignment to me. I don't mind helping out but at the same time I don't want to give the full solution.

The exercise itself looks like generating the series:

```
Z' = Z*Z + C
```

For a complex number Z and C. This is commonly done when generating the mandelbrot or julia set.

The function `F` can be written almost like the definition in F#:

```
let f (x, y) (u, v) = (u*u - v*v + x, 2.*u*v + y)
```

The infinite set `S` is generated from a starting point (0,0) and applying the output of `f` on itself over and over again.

An infinite set in F# can be represented using `seq` and you can create them using [seq comprehesions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences)

Once you have an infinite `seq` with the right values you can pick the `ith` value by using [Seq.item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.item%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)